# C# Battleship grid and case implementation issues

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to create a battleship bones module in C# and I have the majority of the code worked out, but I'm getting caught up on trying to mark hits and misses in my code whenever the player guesses correctly or incorrectly.

What I'm trying to do is activate Case "H" and Case "M" when people input the appropriate grid coordinates.

Code is in C#.

What's supposed to be happening:

Basic Battleship. This is my first real project with C# and hiding the ships isn't important to me. I'm just struggling with having the ships' coordinates being replaced with the appropriate X and background/foreground color as assigned in Case H and Case M.

If I'm missing anything and you need any additional information, please let me know!

This is the code I have so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {

            //Basic function that allows the user to enter their 'guesses' for the ship locations.
            printGrid(Grid);
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'exit' to exit.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your guess: ");
            string cons = Console.ReadLine();
            cons.Substring(0, 1);
            cons.Substring(1, 1);
            cons = cons.ToUpper();
            char column = cons[0];
            char row = cons[1];
            int num = cons[0];
            bool result = Int32.TryParse(cons, out num);

            //Disallows the user from entering anything other than what's valid. Valid characters are, obviously, A - J.
            string validChars = "ABCDEFGHIJ";

            //This allows the user to exit the application by typing "Exit" instead of guessing.
            if (cons == "EXIT")
            {
                return;
            }

            //Again, checks to see if the user inputs any numbers higher than what's allotted.
            else if (!validChars.Contains(column) || (num >= 11))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter only A-J, and 1-10 e.g 'B5'");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Column = {1}, Row = {0}", row, column);

        if (result == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guess was a miss!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guess was a hit!");
            }

        }
    }
    private static readonly char[,] Grid = new char[,]
    {
        {'.', '.', '.', '.', 'S', 'S', 'S', '.', '.', '.'},
        {'P', 'P', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
        {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'P'},
        {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'P'},
        {'.', '.', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', '.', '.', '.'},
        {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.'},
        {'.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.'},
        {'.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', 'P', 'P'},
        {'.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.'},
        {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    };
    public static void printGrid(Char[,] Grid)
    {

        //Let's make the layout pretty.
        Console.WriteLine("     |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |  I  |  J   |");
        Console.WriteLine("-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#------#");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 9)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0} ", i + 1);
            }
            else
                Console.Write(" {0}  ", i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                ShipColors(Grid[i, j]);
            }

            //This needs to match the header in order to format properly.
            Console.Write("  |\r\n");
            Console.WriteLine("-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#------#");
        }
    }

    //Now we're going to declare which colors each ship's cell is going to be.
    public static void ShipColors(char useThis)
    {
        /*
         * Legend for each ship name:
         * P = patrol boat
         * S = Submarine
         * B = Battleship
         * A = Aircraft Carrier
        */
        switch(useThis)
            //Going to use case statements here to automatically color any of the grid's cells with any special characters.
            //Using cases allows the grid to be re-organized and still be colored properly.
        {
            case '.':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                //Blank space here needed to be added for formatting the cells properly.
                Console.Write("   ");
                break;
            case 'A':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.Write(" A ");
                break;
                case 'B':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Write(" B ");
                break;
            case 'P':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Write(" P ");
                break;
            case 'S':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Write(" S ");
                break;
            case 'H':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write(" X ");
                break;
            case 'M':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write(" X ");
                break;

        }
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see some issues but they should all be discoverable by just using a debugger and cleaning up your code. Example of clean code you have the line `cons.Substring(1, 1);` which does nothing without being assigned to somethign so that and the other similar line can be removed. the line `int num = cons[0];` will take cons[0] (a char that is the first character of the string) and converts it to an int which is its ascii representation - probably not what you want.

Comment: Then your line `bool result = Int32.TryParse(cons, out num);` probably doesn't do what you want. cons is your input which you expect to be something like "A1" so you would not expect that to be able to be parsed as an integer. Instead you probably wanted to Parse the substring that contains the number (maybe we should have assigned those substring calls to somethign earlier).  A lot of these issues could have been found by just using a debugger to examine the state of the program as it executes. You could have seen that num had a suspicious value and investigated.

Comment: Lastly when asking questions on stack overflow try to keep them specific. This question is pretty vague: "I'm just struggling with having the ships' coordinates being replaced with the appropriate X and background/foreground color as assigned in Case H and Case M.". This question doesn't really tell me anything. "I'm struggling" could be anything from "I have no idea where to start" to "my validation is failing" to "Its reformatting my hard drive every time I run it". Questions should be precise "eg Why does TryParse keep returning 49 instead of 1?" so that they can be easily answered...

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the lack of clarity in what I was trying to achieve. Rufus had answered what I was looking for. I was looking for a solution that would indicate when a grid coordinate was being hit or not. I was also getting stuck on replacing the appropriate grids with the appropriate 'hit' or 'miss' letters.

Comment: Welp, I thought hitting enter would give me an additional line of whitespace, but it didn't. Thank you guys for all of your input and I'll make sure that my future posts are very clear and concise in regards to what it is I'm actually looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do a lot in one method. Ideally you might break it out into several method calls - one to validate the input, one to check for a hit, another to re-draw the grid with some indicator of the spot they just guessed.

But, to help with this particular problem, after you've done validation that the input was correct, you just need to do something like:

1. Convert the input row to an index. We display our rows starting with `1`, but array indexes start with `0`, so we need to subtract one from their input.
2. Convert the input column to an index. We know that the character `A` has an int value of `65`, and since `A` is the first row, we subtract `65` from the column to get the index.

Then it's just a matter of checking in our `Grid` array at index `[newRow, newCol]` to see if it contains a Letter:

```
if (char.IsLetter(Grid[rowNumber, colNumber]))
{
    Console.WriteLine("HIT!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("MISS.");
}
```

Here is a semi-cleaned up version of your code:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Enter your guess: ");
    string userGuess = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    if (userGuess == "EXIT") return;

    int rowNumber;

    // Validate input
    if (userGuess.Length < 2 || userGuess.Length > 3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess must be in the form of ColumnRow, like: B5");
    }
    else if (!"ABCDEFGHIJ".Contains(userGuess[0]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess must begin with a valid column letter (A-J)");
    }
    else if (!int.TryParse(userGuess.Substring(1), out rowNumber)
             || rowNumber < 1 || rowNumber > 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess must end with a valid row number (1-10)");
    }
    else
    {
        // Valid input! Set actual indexes for the guess
        int colNumber = userGuess[0] - 65;
        rowNumber--;

        if (char.IsLetter(Grid[rowNumber, colNumber]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HIT!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MISS.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rufus, this is perfect! Thank you very much for breaking it down Barney style for me as well. As a beginner of C# I was a bit hesitant to post on here because of the negative barrages that newbies usually get hit with. Your solution not only clarified all questions that I had, but also provided with a great cleaned up version of the spaghetti that I've been boiling for too long. Thank you!